# How to pass file for its particular id uising Angular

Tags: angular

I'm able to pass the file to folder, but I'm not able to pass its id along with it.I'm using ng2-file-upload.I'm performing this upload operation inside mat-dialog box.I'm getting the spf id inside dialog, but don't know how to send it to url. Is there any other method to post the file with its id?Its giving this.attachment list is undefined
Code
html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="item.upload()"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

ts:

```
           import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
        import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
        import { Http,Response,Headers } from "@angular/http";
        import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
        import { FileSelectDirective, FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload';
        import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
        import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';


    const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/file/upload/';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-upload-pdf',
      templateUrl: './upload-pdf.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./upload-pdf.component.css']
    })

   export class UploadPdfComponent implements OnInit {
  id =""
  url : string ;
  attachmentList : any[];
  uploader: FileUploader;

  constructor(private routes : ActivatedRoute , public dialogRef :MatDialogRef<UploadPdfComponent>,private dialog: DialogService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)
     {
      this.id = this.data.id;
      this.url = `${uri}/${this.id}`;
      this.uploader =  new FileUploader({url : this.url});
      this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item:any,response:any,status:any,headers :any)=>{
        this.attachmentList.push(JSON.parse(response));

       }

      } 
  ngOnInit() {

    let body : any = {
      "Spf_id":this.id
      }
    console.log("SPF_id inside upload", body)
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string literal feature here.
**Edit**: creating the object after the url string is contructed

```
 const uri = "http://localhost:3000/file/upload";
        private url: string; 
uploader: FileUploader;
          ngOnInit() {
           this.url: `${uri}/${this.id}`;
           this.uploader = = new FileUploader({url : this.url});
            let body : any = {
              "Spf_id":this.id
              }
            console.log("SPF_id inside upload", body)
          }
```

Comment: Can you use this inside my code. Its not working when I tried.I uri is a bottom and it needs to passed at top it will give uri as null.I'm not getting where to place your code exactly.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: Its giving this.uploader is undefined. I have edited my code, please go through it .Thanks for the help

Comment: Initialize the array. `this.attachmentList: any[] = []`.